# How to automate a java program

Tags: java, jsoup

i have written a java program of scraping and i want to automate it to run the scraping everyday at a specific time.

this is the code

```
private static class DateObject{

        private Double taxes;
        private Double price;
        private Double htPrice;

        public DateObject(Double price, Double htPrice, Double taxes){
            this.taxes = taxes;
            this.price = price;
            this.htPrice = htPrice;
        }

        public Double getTaxes() {
            return taxes;
        }

        public Double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public Double getHtPrice() {
            return htPrice;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, DateObject> prices = new TreeMap<String, DateObject>();
        File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\Test.xls");

        WritableWorkbook myexcel = null;

        try {

            myexcel = Workbook.createWorkbook(f);
            WritableSheet mysheet = myexcel.createSheet("AirFrance ", 0);

            Response response = Jsoup
                    .connect("http://www.airfrance.fr/vols/paris+tunis")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36")
                    .method(Method.GET)
                    .timeout(2000)
                    .execute();

            Document doc = Jsoup
                    .connect("http://www.airfrance.fr/FR/fr/local/vols/getInstantFlexNewCalendar.do?idMonth=10&itineraryNumber=1")
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .timeout(2000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36")
                    .referrer("http://www.airfrance.fr/vols/paris+tunis").get();

            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(doc.text());

            JSONArray dates = (JSONArray) obj.get("days");

            JSONObject dateObject;

            for(Object o : dates){
                if ( o instanceof JSONObject ) {
                    dateObject = ((JSONObject)o);
                    prices.put(dateObject.get("dallasDate").toString(), new DateObject((Double)dateObject.get("price"), (Double)dateObject.get("HTprice"), (Double)dateObject.get("taxes")));
                }
            }

            addLabel(mysheet, 0, 0, "Date");
            addLabel(mysheet, 1, 0, "Prix [€]");
            addLabel(mysheet, 2, 0, "PrixHt [€]");
            addLabel(mysheet, 3, 0, "Taxes [€]");

            int rowIndex = 1;
            DateObject date;

            for (String key : prices.keySet()) {
                date = prices.get(key);
                addLabel(mysheet, 0, rowIndex, key);
                addLabel(mysheet, 1, rowIndex, ""+date.getPrice());
                addLabel(mysheet, 2, rowIndex, ""+date.getHtPrice());
                addLabel(mysheet, 3, rowIndex, ""+date.getTaxes());
                rowIndex++;
            }

        myexcel.write();

        System.out.println("Scraping finished without errors.");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                myexcel.close();
            } catch (WriteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void addLabel(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
            throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
        Label label;
        label = new Label(column, row, s);
        sheet.addCell(label);
    }
```

And i want also to receive an error mail if scrapping went wrong. Any help please

Comment: "i have written". Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this. [Cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for example: these can run at a given time every day (or every hour, or every month). However, when it comes to error reporting on failed Cron jobs, that takes some more advanced know-how in the *nix space which maybe you aren't interested in tackling at this time.

Java itself has a number of scheduler frameworks, which can execute your jobs on a regular basis. [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is one. And while I haven't tried it yet, [Obsidian Scheduler](http://obsidianscheduler.com/) is another that some of my co-workers brought to me as a replacement for Quartz, recently. But these names are all just anecdotes and their viability is subject to change over time. Suffice it to say, these things are already created for you to use as third-party libraries and you should research them to determine which is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Run it under a [crontab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98914/how-to-use-crontab-for-a-java-file-in-linux).

As for an error email... that's an entirely different question and up to you.

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: @hamzaelhadj then google "crontab for windows" or something

Comment: Thank you @djechlin